# Gridview Footer

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have one R & D for displaying the grid view footer on page loading. In my 
application i hit the add button the grid footer displayed with 3 text boxes and previously added values. When i clicking Add button it shows the values that are previously added and i have to scroll to get the text boxes. My requirement is that when the add button is clicked, the text boxes will be shown. is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Use in your page MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack.

```
Page.MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack = true;
```